# Google Push Notification

Tags: android, cloud, google-cloud-messaging

Just now Google introduced Google Cloud Messaging for Android. But here problem is that end user must have atleast one google account to use this service. is possible to skip GCM and send push notification end user or suggest any other way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use GCM user have to be registered in goggle service. If you distribute you application only by Google Play this is not a problem.

There are alternatives but they have lots of disadvantages: sending SMS (you have to pay for it); implement own Push Notifications (by polling your server) - it is easy to make some mistake and drain phones battery and requires lots of work.

Answer (score 2):

**Important:** C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. At that time C2DM stopped accepting new users and quota requests. C2DM has been replaced by [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) (GCM). The C2DM service will continue to be maintained in the short term, but developers must use GCM for new development. We also encourage developers to move existing C2DM applications to GCM to take advantage of GCM features. See the C2DM-to-GCM [Migration document](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is part of C2DM prerequisite Can't skip this mate.. thanks